# EF core navigation property not loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, navigation-properties

I'm modifying my application to be able to specify navigation properties to load in the repository.

Model: Team and TeamTunerUser can be found in the [domain entites](https://github.com/taconaut/Sppd.TeamTuner/tree/master/Backend/Sppd.TeamTuner.Core/Domain/Entities).

Repository:

```
namespace Sppd.TeamTuner.Infrastructure.DataAccess.EF.Repositories
{
    internal class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets the entity set.
        /// </summary>
        protected DbSet<TEntity> Set => Context.Set<TEntity>();

        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets the DB context.
        /// </summary>
        protected TeamTunerContext Context { get; }

        public Repository(TeamTunerContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
        }

        public async Task<TEntity> GetAsync(Guid entityId, IEnumerable<string> includeProperties = null)
        {
            TEntity entity;
            try
            {
                entity = await GetQueryableWithIncludes(includeProperties).SingleAsync(e => e.Id == entityId);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException(typeof(TEntity), entityId.ToString());
            }

            return entity;
        }

        protected IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryableWithIncludes(IEnumerable<string> includeProperties = null)
        {
            var queryable = Set;

            if (includeProperties == null)
            {
                return queryable;
            }

            foreach (var propertyName in includeProperties)
            {
                queryable.Include(propertyName);
            }

            return queryable;
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task TestNavigationPropertyLoading()
    {
        // Arrange
        var teamId = Guid.Parse(TestingConstants.Team.HOLY_COW);

        // Act
        Team createdTeamWithoutUsers;
        Team createdTeamWithUsers;
        using (var scope = ServiceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var teamRepository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IRepository<Team>>();

            createdTeamWithoutUsers = await teamRepository.GetAsync(teamId);
            createdTeamWithUsers = await teamRepository.GetAsync(teamId, new[] {nameof(Team.Users)});
        }

        // Assert
        Assert.Null(createdTeamWithoutUsers.Leader);
        Assert.False(createdTeamWithoutUsers.Users.Any());
        Assert.False(createdTeamWithUsers.CoLeaders.Any());

        Assert.NotNull(createdTeamWithUsers.Leader);
        Assert.True(createdTeamWithUsers.Users.Any());
        Assert.True(createdTeamWithUsers.CoLeaders.Any());
    }
```

My issue is that the `Users` navigation property never gets loaded and the second assertion block fails.

The Team is configured here ([class](https://github.com/taconaut/Sppd.TeamTuner/blob/master/Backend/Sppd.TeamTuner.DataAccess.EF/TeamTunerContext.EntityConfigurations.cs)):

```
    private static void ConfigureTeam(EntityTypeBuilder<Team> builder)
    {
        ConfigureDescriptiveEntity(builder);

        builder.HasMany(e => e.Users)
               .WithOne(e => e.Team);

        // Ignore calculated properties
        builder.Ignore(e => e.Members)
               .Ignore(e => e.Leader)
               .Ignore(e => e.CoLeaders);
    }
```

The (debug) logs don't contain anything useful, except that I see that the join required to load navigation properties is not being executed on SQL level:

```
2019-04-11 16:02:43,896 [14] DEBUG Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection - Opening connection to database 'Sppd.TeamTuner-TEST' on server '.\SQLEXPRESS'.
2019-04-11 16:02:43,901 [14] DEBUG Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection - Opened connection to database 'Sppd.TeamTuner-TEST' on server '.\SQLEXPRESS'.
2019-04-11 16:02:43,903 [14] DEBUG Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command - Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@__entityId_0='?' (DbType = Guid)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(2) [m].[Id], [m].[Avatar], [m].[CreatedById], [m].[CreatedOnUtc], [m].[DeletedById], [m].[DeletedOnUtc], [m].[Description], [m].[FederationId], [m].[IsDeleted], [m].[ModifiedById], [m].[ModifiedOnUtc], [m].[Name]
FROM [Team] AS [m]
WHERE ([m].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([m].[Id] = @__entityId_0)
2019-04-11 16:02:43,920 [12] INFO  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command - Executed DbCommand (16ms) [Parameters=[@__entityId_0='?' (DbType = Guid)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(2) [m].[Id], [m].[Avatar], [m].[CreatedById], [m].[CreatedOnUtc], [m].[DeletedById], [m].[DeletedOnUtc], [m].[Description], [m].[FederationId], [m].[IsDeleted], [m].[ModifiedById], [m].[ModifiedOnUtc], [m].[Name]
FROM [Team] AS [m]
WHERE ([m].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([m].[Id] = @__entityId_0)
2019-04-11 16:02:43,945 [12] DEBUG Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command - A data reader was disposed.
2019-04-11 16:02:43,985 [12] DEBUG Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection - Closing connection to database 'Sppd.TeamTuner-TEST' on server '.\SQLEXPRESS'.
2019-04-11 16:02:43,988 [12] DEBUG Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection - Closed connection to database 'Sppd.TeamTuner-TEST' on server '.\SQLEXPRESS'.
2019-04-11 16:02:45,054 [12] DEBUG Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection - Opening connection to database 'Sppd.TeamTuner-TEST' on server '.\SQLEXPRESS'.
2019-04-11 16:02:45,057 [12] DEBUG Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection - Opened connection to database 'Sppd.TeamTuner-TEST' on server '.\SQLEXPRESS'.
2019-04-11 16:02:45,060 [12] DEBUG Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command - Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@__entityId_0='?' (DbType = Guid)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(2) [m].[Id], [m].[Avatar], [m].[CreatedById], [m].[CreatedOnUtc], [m].[DeletedById], [m].[DeletedOnUtc], [m].[Description], [m].[FederationId], [m].[IsDeleted], [m].[ModifiedById], [m].[ModifiedOnUtc], [m].[Name]
FROM [Team] AS [m]
WHERE ([m].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([m].[Id] = @__entityId_0)
2019-04-11 16:02:45,067 [14] INFO  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command - Executed DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[@__entityId_0='?' (DbType = Guid)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(2) [m].[Id], [m].[Avatar], [m].[CreatedById], [m].[CreatedOnUtc], [m].[DeletedById], [m].[DeletedOnUtc], [m].[Description], [m].[FederationId], [m].[IsDeleted], [m].[ModifiedById], [m].[ModifiedOnUtc], [m].[Name]
FROM [Team] AS [m]
WHERE ([m].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([m].[Id] = @__entityId_0)
2019-04-11 16:02:45,092 [14] DEBUG Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command - A data reader was disposed.
2019-04-11 16:02:45,143 [14] DEBUG Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection - Closing connection to database 'Sppd.TeamTuner-TEST' on server '.\SQLEXPRESS'.
2019-04-11 16:02:45,153 [14] DEBUG Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection - Closed connection to database 'Sppd.TeamTuner-TEST' on server '.\SQLEXPRESS'.
```

What I've tried:

- Do not specify string but an expression to specify navigation property to load:

  ```
  protected IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryableWithIncludes(IEnumerable<string> includeProperties = null)
  {
      var queryable = Set;

      if (includeProperties == null)
      {
          return queryable;
      }

      if (typeof(TEntity) == typeof(Team))
      {
          // TODO: Remove this block once it works by including by string properties
          foreach (var propertyName in includeProperties)
          {
              if (propertyName == "Users")

              {
                  queryable.OfType<Team>().Include(entity => entity.Users);
              }
          }
      }
      else
      {
          foreach (var propertyName in includeProperties)
          {
              queryable.Include(propertyName);
          }
      }

      return queryable;
  }
  ```
- Explicitly configure the relation for the user entity as well:

  ```
  private static void ConfigureTeamTunerUser(EntityTypeBuilder<TeamTunerUser> builder)
  {
      ConfigureDescriptiveEntity(builder);

      builder.HasMany(e => e.CardLevels)
             .WithOne(e => e.User);

      builder.HasOne(e => e.Team)
             .WithMany(e => e.Users);

      // Indexes and unique constraint
      builder.HasIndex(e => e.Name)
             .IsUnique();
      builder.HasIndex(e => e.SppdName)
             .IsUnique();
      builder.HasIndex(e => e.Email)
             .IsUnique();
  }
  ```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Include` / `ThenInclude` (and all other EF Core `Queryable` extensions) are like regular LINQ `Queryable` methods (`Select`, `Where`, `OrderBy` etc.) which modify the source `IQueryable<>` and **return** the modified `IQueryable<>`.

Here you simply forgot to use the resulting query, so

```
queryable.Include(propertyName);
```

has the same effect as

```
queryable.Where(e => false);
```

i.e. *no effect*.

Simply change the code to

```
queryable = queryable.Include(propertyName);
```

Comment: Doh, now I feel stupid ;) now the test fails because both have the users set. I guess performing the gets in different scopes will fix this. Thanks!

Comment: this will not work with Ef core in memory provider ? Because i have done it exactly same but my navigation properties are null

Comment: @kuldeep It works for me, at least in the latest official EFC 3.1.5 I'm testing on.

Comment: I noticed that the internal library i use translate the query to Include("Addresses") instead of Include(s => s.Addresses) .. i suspect this might be the problem ?  Am I missing something ? Like enabling lazy loading or something

Comment: @kuldeep Lazy loading is irrelevant when you use eager loading (`Include`). In my tests `Include` string overload also works.

Comment: @IvanStoev It was a duh moment for me. I've been banging my head against the wall since 3 hours and this saved my efforts and time. Man you are a rockstar!! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a few issues.

Your approach only works for loading the first level of navigation properties.

```
foreach (var propertyName in includeProperties)
{
    queryable.Include(propertyName);
}
```

You must use `.ThenInclude()` for loading nested navigation properties. That breaks your approach of `IEnumerable<string> includeProperties = null` as a constructor though.

The second issue is with your test itself. It only checks `.Any()`, but per the name of the test, that is the wrong assertion. (We don't know if the test is failing because the navigation property never loaded *OR* it did load successfully, but there are zero `Users`. You should only be checking that the navigation property was loaded. Something like the following.

`DbContext.Entry(createdTeamWithUsers).Navigation("Users").IsLoaded`

Comment: You can load nested navigation properties (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-2.1&viewFallbackFrom=efcore-2.2), so your first point should be covered. For your second, I agree, it's not finished yet :)

Comment: You're right, you can load using chains `Team.Users.Whatever` etc. I would advise against this approach though because *magic strings* and use expressions instead to get more compile time safety.

Comment: You're right, I'm still in the process of designing. There's always the possibility to override the base methods in a specialised repo. Here I'd like to have a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did your try marking your properties as virtual? You need it to enable lazy loading navigation as per the docs:

> Lazy Loading
>
> EF Core will then enable lazy loading for any navigation property that can be overridden--that is, it must be virtual and on a class that can be inherited from. For example, in the following entities, the Post.Blog and Blog.Posts navigation properties will be lazy-loaded.
>
> [Source: Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading)

Comment: Question is for EF Core, not EF6 so this is not relevant.

Comment: No I hadn't. I've tried to declare Team.Users as virtual, but the SQL query and the result remians the same. I don't want to use lazy loading, but explicitly specify the navigation properties to load with what I'm trying to implement here.

Comment: @DavidG My answer stands correct in both version of EF. I've update my link to EF core, however it doesn't really mater since it doesn't answer op question anyway.